# I have a responsive menu that i want to display his respective sections when each is clicked just plain javascript, no libraries or so

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, onclick, responsive-slides

[[here is the site and the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ordd5.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCaqR.jpg)

So guys i want to display on each section his respective articles but i cant seem to get the right function, i tried with changing the display on click but its just not looking good

I contained each section whitin divs to have them display change on click but is just looking awful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.